# How to properly intercept JavaScript Function inside a Java String in JSP

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, barcode

i would like to make a call of a `JavaScript` function inside a `String` in `JSP` as follows:

This is the String:

```
<%String x = "https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=&amp;size=100x100";%>
```

This is where i would like to intercept `js`

```
<%String x = "https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=%>here()<%&amp;size=100x100";%>
```

That's pretty odd that this is inside a `String`, these are my questions:

- Do i have to return a `String` value?
- Is it okay if the function's return type is void?

**The function's goal is to make a post request, is it possible?**

---

This is how i'm trying to achieve it:

This is inside `<head>`
`usr` parameter is already initialized

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
function generate(){

xhttp.open("GET","/api/otp/generate?username="+usr, true);
xhttp.send();
return "done"

}
```

and this is inside `<body>`

```
<%String x = "https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=";%>          
<%String z=%>return generate()
<%String y="&amp;size=100x100";
 String w = x+z+y; %>
```

Comment: I can't make much sense of your question. JavaScript is not executed inside strings. Can you provide a bit more context?

Comment: yes, i'd like to make there a specific call of a js function that will return a string to be concatenated in there

Comment: i provided some extra context hope it helps

Comment: It seems that you are mixing up the code that is executed on the server and the code that is executed by JavaScript in the browser. The code within the `<%` and `%>` are executed on your server which is _before_ it is send to the user's browser where the JavaScript can be executed. So at that point you can't execute JavaScript yet. (Unless you use some JS engine, but that seems unpractical.)

Comment: @Ivar i see, if `z="www.google.com"` it works, so why can't `z="done"` and that value is returned from a `js function()`? it work's even if `"z=/something/username="+usr` i'm getting really confused :S

Comment: @Ivar so basically , first `jsp` and then `js` ? but why is that a problem

Comment: Yes, first all the JSP code is executed, then your entire HTML (including the scripts) is send to the browser as a string, then your browser will parse it and execute the JavaScript. You need to look at those two completely separate.

Comment: @Ivar i see... let me add that this is a barcode string, which initializes the barcode below, but that action will happen when the user scans the barcode, should i provide that also?

Comment: I think that i'm starting to make sense of what you said, basically , if i leave it like this `String z` would be probably `null` right? when will it take the value of `js` though?

Comment: As Ivar tries to explain, the key is to realize, **where** and **when** which code is executed - JSP on the server, when the page is requested and rendered (i.e. **before** the response is sent to the browser), and Javascript in the browser, **after** the browser receives the **already generated** response.

Comment: @JozefChocholacek alright, i have to figure out another way to do this